# Create a darken version of an image

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, image-manipulation, rmagick

I need to create a darken version of an image. What is the correct way to accomplish this?
I have tried with the 'modulate' method:

```
manipulate! do |img|
  img.modulate(0.85)
end
```

but the result is not optimal (see Result link).

[Original](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/555626/listing_selected_clarin.jpg)
[Result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/555626/listing_normal_clarin.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RMagick Transformation Script`](http://asset-compiler.rubyforge.org/classes/RMagickTransformationScript.html#M000010) has a `darken` method which may be better suited to this:

```
img.darken      # darkens the image 25%.
img.darken 0.40 # darkens the image 40%.
```

Comment: I think this method is from an asset_compiler gem class (RMagickTransformationScript), not from RMagick, but I've taken the code from that methods (darken & tilt) and it works beautifully (use colorize method). Thanks a lot!